# writing an char array in line with white spaces

Tags: c

The problem is to input some n elements in a line and make an array in c language.
The format of input is This.

input:

15 //number of elements

1 4 4 2 3 5 6 x x x x x x 5 7 // elements

I tried it by using a scanf function, but it didn't work.

```
char* tree;
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
tree = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%c", &tree[i]);
}
```

what's the problem of this code?

Comment: because `char` and `int` are not same, instead of `char*` use `int*` and use `%d` in `scanf` for reading numbers

Comment: Another problem is that you do not read the spaces separating the numbers. Try `scanf(" %d", &tree[i])`. And always check the return value from scanf. It should be 1. If it isn't there's a problem.

Comment: I did it already, but putting a char "x" in an array was impossible in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Some what better program would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int* numbers = NULL;
    
    printf("How many elements do you want to store:");
    do {
        if(1 != scanf("%d",&n)) {
            puts("error in scanf");
            n = 0;
        }

        if(n <= 0)
            printf("Enter a positive number:");
    }while(n <= 0);
    
    numbers = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    
    if( numbers == NULL) {
        puts("malloc failed");
        return 0;
    }
    
    printf("\n Enter %d number of elements:", n);
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)
        if (1 != scanf("%d", &numbers[i]))
            printf("error reading input\n");

    printf("\n The Entered elements are: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    
    free(numbers);
    numbers = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```